# android add and remove mark without call clear()

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I have a map, when the camera is moved it will call api to get data and add new markers.

e.g first time I get 4 markers [a b c d] from api

and after I drag the map I get [b c d e] from api

I dont want to call map.clear() and then add new, as this will cause a flash (all markers disappear and come back)

what is an efficent way to to just remove "a" and add "e"
I was trying to avoid using for loops (will need to compare all the data based on their lat/lng, may slow on heap marks).

I found someone uses QuadTree to achieve this, but not sure how it exactly works.

**UPDATE**: the key point is how to find which marks to remove and which marks to add

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove a `Marker`from the map doing `marker.remove();`. For example:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40, 4)));

// More code

marker.remove();
```

In your case you can use a `HashMap` to maintain your `Marker`s with a given ID and then query the `HashMap` to remove them from the map:

```
private Map<String, Marker> markers = new HashMap<>();

//

markers.put("markerName", mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40, 4)))); // Add the marher to the map and to the hashmap

markers.remove("markerName") // Find and remove the marker from the hashmap
       .remove();            // Remove the marker from the map
```

Comment: but I need to compare 2 date set to find which markers to remove and which to add, I am looking for a better way to find them rather than doing in the for loop

Comment: this may help, I can use id as key, but I still need an iteration to find out which mark needs to be removed, and hashMap is heavy for memory.